# Testing the effect of a categorical variable while controlling a continuous one?

Tags: r, regression

I'm fairly new to statistics and would appreciate some help with something that is probably quite trivial, really.

In my dataset, I have a continuous response variable "depth", and two independent variables; "gc", which is continuous, and "chr" which is categorical with two categories, "A" and "X".

I have already observed that "depth" and "gc" are positively correlated, and that "A" has higher mean "gc" than "X". "A" also has higher mean "depth" than "X", which is unsurprising given the positive correlation between "depth" and "gc".

What I would like to know is whether "chr" has any effect on "depth" if "gc" is controlled for. In other words, does "chr" affect "depth" independently of "gc", or is the apparent affect of "chr" on "depth" solely through the association of "chr" with "gc".

I hope I am making sense. My apologies if my terminology is incorrect.

I would prefer a solution in R, but I would happily use solutions in python, perl, or really anything.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So far you have described a standard regression setting.  Could you indicate what aspect(s) of your data have caused you to reject conventional solutions such as ordinary least squares?

Comment: So far I have tried to run a glm. The problem is that my independent variables are colinear ("chr" strongly predicts "gc"), and so far I haven't figured out how to control for "gc" when testing the ability of "chr" to predict "depth". Again, sorry if this is trivial stuff; I am new to all this and mostly self-taught (or rather, self-teaching...)

Comment: What harmful effects are you detecting from the collinearity?  If there aren't any, then you don't have a problem.

Comment: I'm just worried that my tests for the effect of "chr" on "depth" are only really picking up the effect of "gc" on "depth", since "chr" and "gc" are so strongly associated. Thanks for taking the time to respond.

Comment: Analyzing that situation must depend on the results.  If you find both effects to be significant, you're probably fine.  If not, you might want to explore the trivariate relationship more closely.  But that's something that needs to be done before fitting the model in the first place, so you already should have a good sense of the relationships in your data.